# create a iso ubuntu image system file with packer (with intermediate few provisionning)

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, packer

I work with packer for generate a vagrant box. But lot of error and change in provisionners script happend.

And it's very very too long to restart again all the construct base image linux for provisionning after just for testing one thing in my provisionning script.

Is there a solution for creating iso file which can re use of base for packer previously created by packer itself ?

Upgrade iso provisionning by each step done in my provisionning script shell.

Comment: why dont you do a base box for vagrant and run the provisionning from vagrant only ? basically most of boxes on altas for example are base box (ISO) + chef / puppet and a few tools needed for provisioner to run

Comment: This don't changes anything for my question and problem. I want generate iso for intermediate provisionning (technology provisionning is not important)

Comment: well if you test your provisioning directly with vagrant you dont need to recreate the OS image from ISO etc so at least its faster .. once your provisionning is tested, you can put it back in packer

Comment: I know that and this is not dealing with the question.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no strait forward way of creating an iso from a vagrant box.

What you probably should do is improve your workflow. Try `-on-error=ask` and the `debug` builder to iron out your provisioner scripts.

Comment: And it's possible to create a vagrant box FROM a vagrant box ?

Comment: Yes, but you have to unpack it and then use `virtualbox-ova` etc.